# JavaScript Unwanted Delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, code-organization, onmouseover

If you visit http://www.thebattleforarcadia.com/construction/index.html and open the site in multiple tabs or windows, you might notice the scripts exhibiting delays on the page while including another page that uses Ajax and or JavaScript.

This is especially noticeable when it comes to the mouseovers

Is there any fix for this? I believe that I have organized the JavaScript/jQuery quite a bit, and would like some advice if not code-fixes.

Comment: I am getting Error: $("#slider").slider is not a function
Source File: /construction/javascript/navigation.js
Line: 3
on all pages. I am not seeing any delay

Comment: Is it just me, or does that question not make sense at al? Please check your grammar and sentence structure to make it more readible

Comment: I dont know how this question got 2 votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no delay as far as I'm concerned. It might just be delaying on your end depending on how fast your computer may be, what browser you're using, and etc.

On my end, it runs just fine. Multiple tabs open, no speed decrease. Unless you weren't specific enough and I'm missing something. Otherwise, the mouseovers are normal and I don't experience any delay within the page.

Comment: @Mike: Okay, that makes enough sense, whether it be my processor, memory, and or graphics card, either way if it's not occurring for anyone else, that'll do. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the problem either. All smooth. Could you be more specific in describing WHAT exactly is being shown delayed?